# Is my website being crawled?

Tags: web-crawler, mean-stack, digital-ocean, sendgrid

I have a mean-stack website hosted in a DigitalOcean & nginx & ubuntu server.

In the website, there is a webpage with a button to allow users to send me a message:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-theme" ng-click="mySubmit()">Send Message</button>
```

in the controller:

```
$scope.mySubmit = function () {
    return $http.post('/httpOnly/request/addRequest', { "name": $scope.name, "mail": $scope.mail, "message": $scope.message })
}
```

Then, in the backend, it uses https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs to send me emails.

Previously, everything was fine. However, for 1 week, I received every day 7 mails in a row with `undefined` values. The 7 mails arrived at almost same time every day.

Does anyone know what is happening? Is my website being crawled? Is there a way to verify that?

Comment: you could use a captcha for avoiding automatic usages of your email button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is almost definitely yes. You should be able to verify that by checking your nGinx logs and looking for standard bot user-agent fields.

There is a difference between being crawled by good bots (probably desirable, in order to appear in search engines) and being spam posted to by bad bots. These are often simply trying to post to e.g. blog comments sections with spammy links etc.

To manage which goods bots crawl you, you should use [robots.txt](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt).

Bad bots on the other hand, won't respect robots.txt, and might even spoof their user agents, so you can't block them using that.

A captcha, or [recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/android.html) challenge would work. Alternatively consider using a [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com) account. They implement a configurable web application firewall between the internet and your site, and block a lot of this type of activity automatically.

Comment: Thank you... could you tell more about how to avoid this?

Comment: @SoftTimur  - I have edited my answer with some additional ideas